# HTTParty GET to Fingercheck API gives 401

Tags: ruby, httparty

I am trying to use HTTParty in irb to test an API call, but I keep getting a 401. Attempts to do a `get` against the same URL with the same header info using the Postman Chrome add-on work fine -- any ideas?

```
irb> HTTParty.get("https://developer.fingercheck.com/api/v1/Employees/GetAllEmployees",
                  :headers => {"APIKEY" => "ABCD1234-1234-ABCD-EFGH-ABCD1234ABCD123",
                               "ClientSecretKey" => "ABCD1234-1234-ABCD-EFGH-ABCD1234ABCD123", 
                               "Content-Type" => "application/json"})

=> <HTTParty::Response:0x8 parsed_response=nil, @response=#<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 Unauthorized readbody=true>, 
     @headers={"cache-control"=>["no-cache"], "pragma"=>["no-cache"], 
     "expires"=>["-1"], "server"=>["Microsoft-IIS/7.5"], "x-aspnet-version"=>["4.0.30319"], 
     "x-powered-by"=>["ASP.NET"], "date"=>["Mon, 01 Dec 2014 21:04:32 GMT"], 
     "connection"=>["close"], "content-length"=>["0"]}>
```

I have also tried to do the `get` call with `:query=>...`, `:query => {:header...`, and `:basic_auth =>...`, but none change the results. Any ideas?

I know a fair number of HTTParty questions have been asked and answered, but I didn't see anything that spoke to this particular issue.

The documentation I know of for the API is at http://developer.fingercheck.com/api/help

Comment: How are you supposed to be authenticating? Is it url based? in which case it would be `query:{}` or basic authentication in which case use `basic_auth:{}`. If it is digest authentication then this would be specified outside of the request using the `digest_auth` method. Since you do not specify how the authentication is supposed to occur and did not supply any reference docs it is difficult to help. I could give you examples of each but knowing exactly what you need seems more appropriate.

Comment: The authentication is based on the APIKEY and ClientSecretKey, as best I can tell. The API is through FingerCheck (http://developer.fingercheck.com/api/help), I don't *think* either of those auth options is what I need (tested both, neither works).

Comment: A coworker was also able to successfully pull data from the API using `curl -X GET -H "APIKEY: ABCD1234-1234-ABCD-EFGH-ABCD1234ABCD123" -H "ClientSecretKey: ABCD1234-1234-ABCD-EFGH-ABCD1234ABCD123" https://developer.fingercheck.com/api/v1/Employees/GetAllEmployees`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error turned out to be a problem with the API, not with the code -- our headers were being read as 'Apikey' and 'Clientsecretkey' and therefore failing some equality on their side. A fix was pushed to production by them, code now functional.

Answer (score 0):

Add `'Accept' => 'application/json'` to your request headers.